# Python - when a variable varies

Tags: python

I'm making a basic code for my python bot, but i encountered a problem: let's suppose that i have A variable, since A is a variable that is taken from an API, it's value changes. I want my bot to Print X when A varies of x% (for example, 10%). I know how to make the if statement but the problem is the percentage part, is there a way to tell my bot to print something when the variable changes of 10/20/30%?

Comment: Please show some code that you have tried that isn't working.

Comment: This question is missing loads of context. Can you share some code?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or a code writing service. Please take the time to read [ask] and the links it contains.  You should spend some time working your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), practicing the examples. It will give you an introduction to the tools Python has to offer and you may even start to get ideas for solving your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the value of `A` is a **number** then this will work:

```
percent_change = 100 * (new_A - old_A) / old_A
```

Or if you don't want negatives:

```
import math

percent_change = math.fabs(100 * (A_final - A_initial) / A_initial)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Considering the value hold by the variable is of *string* type:** Firstly you should determine the logic based on which you calculate the difference of values.

For example, below is the sample code which determine the difference based on two conditions:

- Value at each index of the older and newer string
- If two strings are of different length, fill the missing characters with '|'. Then calculate *percentage* change based on the length of bigger string.

Sample code:

```
>>> from itertools import zip_longest
>>> old_a = 'Hello'
>>> new_a = 'World X'
>>> (sum(i!=j for i, j in zip_longest(old_a, new_a, fillvalue='|'))/max(len(old_a), len(new_a)))*100
85.71428571428571
```

Comment: @Matt5 If you are looking for the string change percentage, then please mention that in question too :)